# Type inference of function resolved from a map and called indirectly

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make typescript typings work with a pattern where there is an *object* of functions and a function `call(name, arg)` which looks up the function in the *object* by `name` and calls it with `arg`.

Suppose that I have an object which maps names to functions:

```js
interface Registry {
  str2numb: (p: string) => number
  num2bool: (p: number) => boolean
}

const REGISTRY: Registry = {
  str2numb: p => parseInt(p, 10),
  num2bool: p => !!p,
}
```

I also have a function `call(name, p)` which resolves the function from the `REGISTRY` and calls it with `p`. Now, I would like to type the function so, that it complains if an invalid argument is provided:

```js
const call = (name, p) => REGISTRY[name](p)

call('str2numb', 123)
//               ^^^ Would like to see an error here
```

How can I resolve the type `P` for the parameter `p` (and also the return type `R`) from the type of `Registry.str2numb`? Is it even possible?

```js
// How can I resolve P and R here?
// The resolved function is Registry[N]
// I have tried Registry[N]<P, R> but that doesn't work :-(
const call = <N extends keyof Registry>(name: N, p: P): R => REGISTRY[name](p)
```

I have gotten this far, but it doesn't work:

```js
type Fn<P, R> = (p: P) => R

const call =
  <N extends keyof Funcs, F extends Funcs[N] & Fn<P, R>, P, R>
    (name: N, p: P): R =>
      REGISTRY[name](p)

call('str2numb', 123)
//               ^^^ No error here
```

This works however:

```js
// This just returns the resolved function
const call1 = <N extends keyof Funcs>(name: N) => REGISTRY[name]

// The type of the returned function is correctly inferred from the name
call1('str2numb')(123)
//                ^^^ Argument of type '123' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to 'extract out' parameter type from a function type in typescript.

If you are willing to do some extra work, you can define types for your registry using a data structure that encodes parameter type and return type separately. That data structure is not used at runtime, but serves only as a guide for a compiler to do type inference, so you can have your `call` type-checked:

```
// used to encode parameter and result type
// like this: param<string>().result<number>()
function param<P>(): { result<R>(): {p: P[], r: R[]}} {
    return {
        result<R>() {
            return {p: [], r: []} // use empty arrays so we don't have 
                                  // to provide values
        }
    }
}

const registryTypes = {
    str2numb: param<string>().result<number>(),
    num2bool: param<number>().result<boolean>()
}
type RegistryTypes = typeof registryTypes;

// this has the same type as `interface Registry` in the question
type Registry = {[N in keyof RegistryTypes]: (p: RegistryTypes[N]['p'][0]) => RegistryTypes[N]['r'][0]};


const REGISTRY: Registry = {
  str2numb: p => parseInt(p, 10),
  num2bool: p => !!p,
}

let call: <N extends keyof RegistryTypes>(n: N, p: RegistryTypes[N]['p'][0]) => RegistryTypes[N]['r'][0];

const n = call('str2numb', '2'); // ok, n is a number
const n1 = call('str2numb', 2); // error
```

Answer (score 1):

I essentially agree with @artem, and am posting this similar-but-not-identical solution for completeness:

```
// type for the compiler
type RegistrySchema = {
  str2numb: { argument: string, result: number };
  num2bool: { argument: number, result: boolean };
}

// represent Registry in terms of RegistrySchema
type Registry = {
  [K in keyof RegistrySchema]:
    (argument: RegistrySchema[K]['argument']) => RegistrySchema[K]['result'] 
}

// same REGISTRY as before
const REGISTRY: Registry = {
  str2numb: p => parseInt(p, 10),
  num2bool: p => !!p,
}

// call can be defined thusly
function call<K extends keyof RegistrySchema>(
  k: K,
  argument: RegistrySchema[K]['argument']
): RegistrySchema[K]['result'] {
  return REGISTRY[k](argument);
}

// it works
const x = call('str2numb', 123); // error
const y = call('str2numb', "hello"); // y is number
```

Good luck!